# How to update an element in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a page with data shown in rows. Each row has an element: Stop or Play. This element is driven by the following code in handlebars:

```
{{#if isactive}}
  <a {{bindAttr href="toggle"}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
{{else}}
  <a {{bindAttr href="toggle"}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
{{/if}}
```

When user clicks "Stop" or "Play" icon, I would like the logic to make a call to the backend server, update the database, and change the icon to either stop or play. I am not sure how to do this in Ember. At the moment, this is how my `toggle` method looks like:

```
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    toggle: function () {
        return "/my/backendserver/"+this.get('id')+"/toggle";
    }.property()
});
```

This works, however, it does a full page reload.

**Question**

How can I modify the `toggle` method so that it only calls the server (providing `id` as parameter, and switches the stop icon to play or vice and versa without doing a complete page reload?)

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? bind-attr is deprecated. Also, are you using Ember Data? Just want to know in order to help make my answer useful to you.

Comment: @Gaurav I am using `v1.0.0-rc.6`. I understand it is old. I haven't invested time in upgrading. I am still trying to find out how to accomplish this in this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to anyone reading this: this answer is written to Ember 1.0.0rc6, and should not be used as an example of writing modern Ember.

So you need to use an action rather than changing the href attribute of an anchor.

In your template:

```
{{#if isactive}}
  <button {{action 'toggle'}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
{{else}}
  <button {{action 'toggle'}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
{{/if}}
```

In your controller:

```
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isactive: false,
  actions: {
    toggle() {
      var _this = this;
      fetch('/my/backendserver/'+this.get('id')+'/toggle').then(function() {
        _this.toggleProperty('isactive');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

By the way, I probably have some syntax details wrong, that version is over 6 years old, which is just forever in JavaScript time. And I'm not testing this.

Answer (score -1):

You can eliminate the `if` statement and use an `if` statement inside the class, which will show the play icon if active is true and stop if it is false,  and call the action inside `span`:

```
<a><span class="glyphicon {{if active 'glyphicon-play' 'glyphicon-stop'}}" {{action "toggle"}} aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question.